# Modal box doesn't open in react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, bootstrap-modal, react-redux

I am working on a React-Redux app, currently working on showing a modal box on a button click of a form. But I can't make it work. I have tried so many things but can't figure out why the modal box doesn't appear. Here is my code.

**The Modal component file**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connectModal } from 'redux-modal'
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
import UpdatePasswordForm from 'forms/updatepassword'

export class UpdatePassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  renderCloseIcon (handleHide) {
    return (
      <button className='close' onClick={ handleHide }>
            <span>
            <i className="modal__close"/>
          </span>
      </button>
    )
  }

  renderModalLogo () {
    return (
      <div className="modal__header modal__header_login">
        <div className="modal__logo"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { show, handleHide } = this.props

    return (
      <Modal
        show={ show }
        onHide={ handleHide }
        backdrop={ true }
        className="modal_dark modal_center"
        dialogClassName="modal-background-fix">
        <div className="modal__container">
          { this.renderCloseIcon(handleHide) }
          { this.renderModalLogo() }
          <div className="modal__content">
            <UpdatePasswordForm onSubmit={() => {}}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

export default connectModal({name: 'updatepassword'})(UpdatePassword)
```

**The form that is loaded in the Modal**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import Text from '../containers/Text'

const I18n = {}
I18n.t = Text.t

const UpdatePasswordForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field name="current_password" component="input"
               type="password" placeholder="Password" className="form-control" />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field name="password" component="input"
               type="password" placeholder="New Password" className="form-control" />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field name="password_confirm" component="input" type="password"
               placeholder="New password confirmation" className="form-control" />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group form-group_btns">
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting} className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
          { 'CHANGE PASSWORD' }
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'updatepassword'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(UpdatePasswordForm)
```

**The file where modal is called**

```
import React from 'react';
import './EditInformation.scss'
import { show } from 'redux-modal'
import UpdatePassword from './Modals/UpdatePassword'

// TODO fix stylee stylee
// TODO onChange is not updating correctly, FIX!

const EditInformation = ({ onSubmit, onChange, user, formSubmitting }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <UpdatePassword />

      <form className='form-line form-line_light'>
        <div className='col-xs-16 col-sm-8'>
              <fieldset className='form-group'>
                <button
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    show('updatepassword')
                    e.preventDefault()                        
                  }}
                  className='btn btn-secondary btn-lg profile-edit__addcard'
                  style={ { position: 'relative', top: '-27px' } }>
                  <i className='fa fa-plus'/>Vaihda salasana
                </button>
              </fieldset>
        </div>
      </form>
   </div>
  );
};

export default EditInformation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a stupid mistake that I have figured out now. But I should get an error for that which I am not getting. I had to pass 'show' to the const EditInformation which I have done now and it is working all fine. Here is that part of the code:

```
const EditInformation = ({ onSubmit, onChange, user, formSubmitting, show }) => {
```

I wasn't passing 'show' previously.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of our project, I tried to develope my own modal with all custom functionalities. Many problems has occured. I searched some open source projects, then I found a project on github. You should use react-modal, It's easy to use and well designed.

[react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal)

Comment: Thank you. But I need to do it with redux-modal that I am using here.

Comment: For reference: [redux-modal](https://github.com/yesmeck/redux-modal/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: Just pass the redux-state to react-modal as props. Reference project just have 18 stars.